# Defining function recursively

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can somebody please let me know if I'm doing this right?

Let f(x) = 2x-2

Define f(x) recursively.

f(1) = 2 - 2 = 0
f(2) = 4 - 2 = 2
f(3) = 6 - 2 = 4
f(4) = 8 - 2 = 6

Answer: f(x)=f(x-1)+2

Comment: A recursive definition requires both a recursion *and initial conditions*.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, am I correct or not?

Comment: $f(x)=f(x-1)+2$ is a correct start, but it is an incomplete answer.  That would also describe $f(x)=2x+8,f(x)=2x-\pi, f(x)=2x+38887$ among infinitely many other functions.  $f(x)=f(x-1)+2$ does not uniquely define $f(x)=2x-2$.  You must also include an initial condition, e.g. $f(0)=-2$

Answer (score 0):

Your computations of $f(x)$ are fine.  Then your experiments indicate that $f(x)=f(x-1)+2$ but you need to prove it.  You can do that from your definition.  Take $f(x)-f(x-1)$ and substitute in the expression you have. Having done that, you should have $f(x)-f(x-1)-2$  Now you need to define $f(a)$ for some $a$ so you get the rest.

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive definition to work you need a base clause so that your recursion doesn't loop forever.

If you define $ f(x)=f(x-1)+2 $ then to find $f(0)$ requires the following computation.

$$ \begin{align} f(0) & =  f(-1) + 2 \\
&=(f(-2) +2) +2\\
&=((f(-3) +2) +2) +2\\
&=\ldots \end{align}$$

To prevent this you have to define a base clause for the smallest $x$ in the domain of $f$.